# XPath Query to find supplier name through an XML table

Tags: sql-server, sqlxml

I am trying to find out the cities where there is a supplier with the name of Herman. We are using XPath through Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

I am not a CIS major and I have no idea where to start. So that's why I'm asking for help...

I have the following table created:

```
CREATE TABLE Tb_Supplier(
XMLColumn XML)
GO

INSERT Tb_Supplier VALUES(
    '<SuppliersList>
      <Supplier name="Joe">
        <City>Paris</City>
        <Product name="Airplane"/>
        <Product name="Milk"/>
        <Product name="TV"/>
        <Product name="Orange"/>
     </Supplier>
      <Supplier name="Herman">
        <City>Chicago</City>
        <Product name="Orange"/>
     </Supplier>
     <Supplier name="Bernstein">
        <City>Madison</City>
        <Product name="Truck"/>
        <Product name="TV"/>
      </Supplier>
     <Supplier name="Hunter">
        <City>Wausau</City>
      </Supplier>
      <Supplier name="Mayer">
        <City>Madison</City>
      </Supplier>
      <Supplier name="Rosenfeld">
        <City>Chicago</City>
        <Product name="Computer"/>
        <Product name="Book"/>
        <Product name="Truck"/>
      </Supplier>
    </SuppliersList>');
```

The output is supposed to show:

```
<City>Chicago</City>
```

I got the it to work by the following:

```
SELECT XMLColumn.query('/SuppliersList/Supplier[@name="Herman"]/City')
FROM Tb_Suppliers
```

---

I am kind of getting the grasp of things.
Currently I am having trouble how to find out the following:
**List the products are TV's, and are offered in Madison.** 
Obviously the output will be  since it is looking for TV.

I have this so far, I don't know what I'm doing wrong as this makes the most sense to me.

```
SELECT XMLColumn.query('/SuppliersList/Supplier/Product[@name="TV"]/../City[@name="Madison"]/../Product')
FROM Tb_Suppliers
```

Comment: What, if anything, have you tried? Nobody is going to write the code for you.

Comment: I don't even know where to start to be completely honest. I'm not in a CIS major but I was stuck taking this class because the reviews were good, I've caught along on pretty much everything besides the sql stuff.

Comment: No good to tell you how to do it, but I'll give you some hints.     https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189075%28SQL.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396    /* find Supplier who have truck-product */ 
 SELECT XMLColumn.query('/SuppliersList/Supplier/Product[@name="Truck"]/..') from Tb_Supplier

Comment: Please avoid follow-up questions! If the initial question is solved you should close this question by accepting he most helpfull answer. Then place your new question as a new question. This will pull new attraction. Nobody will read your edits here (I found them by chance...) Just in short: Put the filter-predicat to a higher node instead of backward navigation.

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether you know, that there is exactly one "Herman" in your list. Then it's a pure call on `.value()` with the appropriate `XPath`:

```
SELECT XMLColumn.value(N'(/SuppliersList/Supplier[@name="Herman"]/City/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Herman_City
FROM Tb_Supplier
```

If you expect more than one, you need `.nodes()` to get a derived table and `value()` on the relative path (below the node coming from `.nodes()`):

```
SELECT AllHerman.cities.value(N'(City/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Herman_City
FROM Tb_Supplier
CROSS APPLY XMLColumn.nodes(N'/SuppliersList/Supplier[@name="Herman"]') AS AllHerman(cities)
```

Answer (score 0):

No good to tell you how to do it, but I'll give you some hints.     https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189075%28SQL.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

```
/* find Supplier who have truck-product */ 
    SELECT XMLColumn.query('/SuppliersList/Supplier/Product[@name="Truck"]/..') from Tb_Supplier
```

@ sign means "attribute".  The url shows how to query element-values (a slightly different syntax than attributes).

"/" means navigate down (or sometimes up) the hierarchy.

".." means "back UP the hierarchy one level".

That should be enough to get you going.

Comment: Thank you, I know enough for the XPath, just not how to use sql queries.

Comment: So my code shows the magic syntax sugar.  "Select MyXmlColumn.query('myxpath') from MyTable.