# XPath for second element with given child value?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have to find out the second `Supplier` with `Chicago` as the city.

I have the following table created.

```
CREATE TABLE Tb_Supplier(
XMLColumn XML)
GO

INSERT Tb_XPathQueryTable VALUES(
    '<SuppliersList>
      <Supplier name="Joe">
        <City>Paris</City>
        <Product name="Airplane"/>
        <Product name="Milk"/>
        <Product name="TV"/>
        <Product name="Orange"/>
     </Supplier>
      <Supplier name="Herman">
        <City>Chicago</City>
        <Product name="Orange"/>
     </Supplier>
     <Supplier name="Bernstein">
        <City>Madison</City>
        <Product name="Truck"/>
        <Product name="TV"/>
      </Supplier>
     <Supplier name="Hunter">
        <City>Wausau</City>
      </Supplier>
      <Supplier name="Mayer">
        <City>Madison</City>
      </Supplier>
      <Supplier name="Rosenfeld">
        <City>Chicago</City>
        <Product name="Computer"/>
        <Product name="Book"/>
        <Product name="Truck"/>
      </Supplier>
    </SuppliersList>');
```

I have to find out the second supplier with Chicago as the city.

I have tried the following code and a few variations:

```
SELECT XMLColumn.query('/SuppliersList/Supplier/City[text()="Chicago"]/../Supplier[2]')
FROM Tb_Supplier
```

When I use the above code without the `/Supplier[2]` it shows both of the suppliers with Chicago.

The output is supposed to have

```
  <Supplier name="Rosenfeld">
    <City>Chicago</City>
    <Product name="Computer"/>
    <Product name="Book"/>
    <Product name="Truck"/>
  </Supplier>
```

Comment: I have to find out the second supplier with Chicago as the city.

I had it posted half way down, sorry

Comment: This question is very - uhm - related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47664562/5089204)...

Answer (score 2):

This XPath,

```
(/SuppliersList/Supplier[City="Chicago"])[2]
```

will select the second `Supplier` with `"Chicago"` as the `City`, as requested.